# My sequence not works all the time postgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I encountered problems when using postgres sql

I have a inteface to add a folder (web application)
I have a table "file" with a column "ref_composant" I automatically generates the following manner.:

Each time you insert a record, I incremented the "ref_composant"
Ref00001
at each insertion is incremented Ref00002, Ref00003 ....
I create the SQL reqette with PostgreSQL

```
    ref_deq character varying(10) DEFAULT ('ref'::text || lpad((nextval('seq_refcomposant'::regclass))::text, 6, '0'::text))

with sequence seq_refcomposant
```

My problem is that this column can't not be null . and in some time when I do insert colone is null

What I have to do in this method while not returning the corect sequence .. it can be null

Comment: Show the insert command

Comment: I work with hibernate !! getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(comp);

Comment: there is a Persoone told me that PostgreSQL has a default with this command .. and I have tried with the triger

Comment: the problem when I try to add a ligne with pgAdmin ..this column is empty and when I refrech the table It appears corectly ref000002 for exemple ..but With my programm not working

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that NOT NULL and CHECK constraints are always checked immediately when a row is inserted or modified (not at the end of the statement).

To work around this, make the column nullable, have a before trigger populate it on inserts, and add an after constraint enforce the not null constraint.

Comment: when I insert a row with my application this column does not work ..
always empty. by cons when I insert manually with pgAdmin box is empty but when I refreshed the line it takes the value I want.